# Как работает оператор ~ инверсии в java?

Tags: java, битовые-операции

Есть код:

```
   for(int i = -2; i<2; i++)
    System.out.printf("Инверсия %d даст %d. \n", i, ~i );
```

На выходе:

```
Инверсия -2 даст 1. 
Инверсия -1 даст 0. 
Инверсия 0 даст -1. 
Инверсия 1 даст -2.
```

Оператор инверсии похоже реализован так:

```
Operator ~ (int i){
return -i-1;
}
```

Но пишут, что инверсия инвертирует нули в единицы. Хорошо, для -2 (инт для упрощения 4 бита берём) 1010, первый бит - знак минус. Значит инверсия будет 0101, то есть 5.  [Дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4): 0101 + 1 = 0110 - итого 6. Короче, никак у меня в теории не удаётся инвертировать код

**Вопрос:** Как на самом деле (объясните на единицах и нулях) работает этот проклятый оператор? И зачем разработчики языка сделали его работу именно такой?

Comment: Ай-яй-яй! -2 это 1110, а не 1010!

Comment: @Эникейщик  C каких таких архитектур? 1110 есть в десятичном коде  0*2^0+1*2^1+1*2^2 = -6 (если первый - это знаковый бит).

Comment: Не знаю с каких архитектур. С очень давних. Введите -2 в виндовый калькулятор в режиме программиста и убедитесь в этом лично. Да и по вашей же ссылке в википедии оно же и написано.

Comment: Вы неправильно переводите отрицательные числа из двоичного вида в десятичный. Там все наоборот.

Comment: @Эникейщик А как надо? Я из википедии так научился переводить.

Comment: Поменять все биты на наоборот, перевести в десятичный вид, прибавить единицу и добавить спереди минус.

Comment: @Эникейщик Вы хотите сказать, что отрицательные значения хранятся в дополнительном коде?

Comment: Я не знаю, как все эти коды называются. Судя по тексту в википедии да, отрицательные числа представлены в дополнительном коде. А вы думали, спереди единичку приписал и число стало отрицательным? :)

Comment: @Эникейщик именно так я и думал.

Comment: Лично мне понять как оно устроено помогла примерно такая картинка https://bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/images/quiz/bit_manipulation/TwosComplementB.png

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо. Благодаря вам всё дошло быстрее. Нужна репа - перенесите апдейт вопроса в свой ответ, я готов принять, так как вы сподвигли.

Comment: Да ладно, на нормальный ответ тут не хватит, а сочинять сейчас неохота :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Инверсия является побитовой операцией и преобразует хранящиеся в памяти единицы в нули и нули в единицы. Чтобы понять почему она так работает с типом int нужно изучит структуру представления примитивного типа `int` в памяти. Примитивный тип `int` состоит из четырех байт. Старший бит старшего байта отвечает за знак числа, остальные - за значение. Отрицательные числа хранятся в [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4).
Разберем пример для числа -2:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-2));
//11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110 - битовое представление числа -2
```

после операции побитовой инверсии мы получим:
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001, что эквивалентно десятичной 1
Таким образом для корректного использования побитовых операций важно знать внутреннюю структуру обрабатываемых данных и при необходимости работать только с нужной частью битов используя маски и сдвиги.
Необходимо учитывать и то, что другие целочисленные типы при многих операциях так же приводятся к типу int.

Comment: Почему, простите -2 у вас 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110 а не 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000010. С каких-таких тьюрингов там единицы взялись?

Comment: Потому что именно так работает компьютер!

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Представление данных в памяти не всегда интуитивно для человека. Но мы можем убедиться как именно представлено в битах конкретное десятичное число с помощью метода Integer.toBinaryString(int);

Comment: @Mark вы всё понимаете, но в обще принятых терминах объясняете не очень грамотно. Поэтому плюсую, но принять ответ не могу. В апдейте вопроса тот ответ, который мне был нужен.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin так напишите сами ответ, и примите его, если Эникейщик не хочет. А то вопрос без принятого ответа - это не очень, да и сильно ударяет по моим перфекционистским чувствам.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Я ответил на вопрос и "Как  работает этот проклятый оператор?" и "почему вывод не соответствует ожиданиям". Вопрос "почему данные представлены в памяти именно так?" по моему мнению это уже следующий вопрос. В "правильном ответе" вы углубляетесь в тип int, а не в работу побитового исключающего или.

Comment: @Mark да забейте вы на репу. Задача сообщества помогать людям чтобы копить базу знаний, а не ради кармадрочерства.

Comment: @Mark есть большое желание -- перенесите апдейт в ответ, подредактируйте, так, чтобы все заходящие сюда поняли  даже если это будут первоклассники, я готов принять на таких условиях и снести нахрен апдейт.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin да не вопрос, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Отрицательные числа компьютер хранит в дополнительном коде. С точки зрения математики, дополнительный код - это кольцо вычетов по модулю 2<sup>N</sup>. Не пугайтесь, это страшное слово означает всего лишь, что к отрицательным числам добавляется 2<sup>N</sup>, где N - число разрядов.

К примеру, 32х-битное число -1 в памяти хранится как 2<sup>32</sup>-1 = 4294967295. Или, в двоичном виде, 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111<sub>2</sub>.

Аналогично, число -2 в памяти хранится как 2<sup>32</sup>-2 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110<sub>2</sub>, а число -3 - как 2<sup>32</sup>-3 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101<sub>2</sub>.

Легко видеть, что инверсия одного бита с точки зрения математики - это вычитание его из 1: 1-1=0, а 1-0=1.
Инверсия же всех 32х бит числа - это вычитание их его из 32х единиц. Но, как уже было показано выше, число состоящее из 32х единиц - это -1.

Таким образом, математически вы правы, оператор инверсии действительно работает так как вы написали:

```
~x = -1-x
```

Но не следует думать что эта формула - его реализация. Это всего лишь его математическое свойство, а реализован он по определению - как инверсия всех бит числа.

Кстати, если перенести единицу в другую часть, получится более интересная формула:

```
~x + 1 = -x
```

Интересна эта формула тем, что является реализацией оператора "унарный минус" в процессоре. Именно так процессоры вычитают целые числа:

```
x - y = x + ~y + 1
```

Comment: "Кольцо вычетов" - вы как просветитель избегайте терминов там, где можно и нужно давать ответ чтобы поняли вас пятиклассники. А так да, спасибо, плюсую.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin я этот термин на пальцах объяснил. А указал я его специально, чтобы было что гуглить если эта тема вас заинтересует.